# Convert htaccess Rule to nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I was wondering if someone could tell me what the nginx rule for the following htaccess code would be. I've searched online but I haven't found anything.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

Answer (score 4):

It would look something like this:

```
server {
    listen        80;
    server_name   nginx.org  www.nginx.org;
    root          /data/www;

    location / {
        index     index.html  index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.(ttf|otf|eot)$ {
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    }
}
```

I'm just writing this from memory, so you'll have to test it. 
The `location ~*` means a regex case insensitive match. All other confs in `server` are informative. Just so you *grok* how these work together.

More info:

- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpHeadersModule
- http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location